# How to make a RUNTIME BUTTON under a RUNTIME GameObject UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine

is there a way we can make a runtime button under a runtime gameobject?i was able to do a runtime gameobject inherited with all the components/materials from UIToolkit.

heres my code:

```
    public class loadImage : MonoBehaviour
{

    public UIToolkit duplicate_kit;
    public Material material;
    public UIButton b1, b2;
    public MeshFilter meshFilter;
    public MeshRenderer meshRenderer;
    public Mesh _mesh;


    void initKit()
    {

        Material duplicateMaterial = new Material (material.shader);
        duplicateMaterial.CopyPropertiesFromMaterial(material);
        material = duplicateMaterial;

        GameObject loadImageToolkit = new GameObject("duplicate_toolkit");
        loadImageToolkit.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("UI").transform;
        loadImageToolkit.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("UILayer");


        duplicate_kit = loadImageToolkit.AddComponent<UIToolkit>() ;
        duplicate_kit.texturePackerConfigName = "friendsImageSheet";
        duplicate_kit.material = duplicateMaterial;

        meshRenderer = loadImageToolkit.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        meshRenderer.renderer.material = duplicateMaterial;

        meshFilter = loadImageToolkit.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        _mesh = meshFilter.mesh;


    }

    void Start()
    {
         initKit();

//       b1 = UIButton.create( duplicate_kit, "FriendsAvatar.png","FriendsAvatar.png",0,0); 
//       b1.pixelsFromTopLeft ( 60, 0 );
//       StartCoroutine(getImage(b1));


         b2 = UIButton.create( duplicate_kit, "FriendsAvatar.png", "FriendsAvatar.png" , 0,0 );
         b2.pixelsFromTopLeft( 120, 0 );
         StartCoroutine(getImage(b2));


         b1 = UIButton.create( (UIToolkit)GameObject.Find("duplicate_toolkit").GetComponent(typeof(UIToolkit)), "FriendsAvatar.png","FriendsAvatar.png",0,0);   
         b1.pixelsFromTopLeft ( 120, 0 );
         StartCoroutine(getImage(b1));

    }

    IEnumerator getImage(UIButton uib)
    {      
        WWW imageRequest = new WWW("https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxx/picture?type=small"); 
        yield return imageRequest;
        Texture tex = imageRequest.texture;

        uib.manager.renderer.material.mainTextureScale = new Vector2(18.0f,20.05f);
        uib.manager.renderer.material.mainTexture = tex;
    }

}
```

the main goal is the b2 button should appeared under duplicate_toolkit(Game Object)

its like :

duplicate_toolkit

> UIButton

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with UITookit but in general you do this in Unity by connecting the [Transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.html) components:

```
b2.transform.parent = duplicate_toolkit.transform;
```

Comment: hi kay!thanks for the reply, it gave me this error Error CS0200: Property or indexer `UnityEngine.GameObject.transform' cannot be assigned to (it is read-only)

Comment: Seems like UIToolkit is doing all its stuff in a different way aside from standard. I just saw that even b2 is not showing up in hierarchy view.

Comment: yes Kay, everything is set up on a runtime script. everything works fine, i mean the component, the only problem is the UIButton which is the bs that does not appear below the duplicate_toolkit runtime game object.